# Cannot use != operator for a list of values

Tags: c#, list, operators

Im trying to create a list of uint values and then use that variable/list in my code to make sure that none of those values inside the list are being used by my code.

Trying to use this method i get an error that
"Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'uint' and 'List<uint>"

```
var list = new List<uint> { 7, 2, 1 };
if(Execute() && InAction() && ID != list 
  return Action;
```

And other ideas would be appreciated

Comment: are you looking for `list.Contains(ID)` ? a `uint` and a `List<uint>` are neither "equal" nor "not equal" - the question itself doesn't make sense

Comment: in order to check if an element is **contained** in a list - which is fundamentally different from checking if it is **equal** (or un-equal) to a list - use `List<T>.Contains`.

Comment: Could an egg ever be equal to an egg carton? The logic we all use every day doesn't change because we're writing code.

Comment: You need to learn about reference variables!! Even with the very same content two lists would not be equal!!!

Answer (score 4):

A value and a list are neither equal nor not equal*; instead, use `Contains` to check whether the value exists *in* the list

```cs
if (Execute() && InAction() && !list.Contains(ID))
```

---

* except for pedantic scenarios for example where a `List<object>` has had itself added to itself; but... yeah

Answer (score 3):

Do this:

```
var list = new List<uint> { 7, 2, 1 };
if(Execute() && InAction() && !list.Contains(ID)) 
{
   return Action;
}
```